# Addition in for loop not working

Tags: bash

I'm writing a small script that calculates the total size of files. I have a file that contains a list of files I have to check, I iterate through them and I want to print out the total size. This is what I've done so far, but for some reason I get 0 as the total

```
for file in `cat $LISTFILES`
do

echo "Processing files: " $file
      actualsize=$(du -b "$file" | cut -f 1)
      sum=0
      sum=$sum+$actualsize
      echo $sum
done

echo 'done'
echo $sum
```

Both of the `echo $sum` returns 0 
I can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: `while IFS= read -r file; do ...; done < "$LISTFILES"`. Your approach will fail if any of the file names contain whitespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are zeroing `sum` in every step:

```
sum=0
while read file; 
do 
echo "Processing files: " $file
      actualsize=$(du -b "$file" | cut -f 1)
      # wrong syntax
      # sum=$sum+$actualsize
      # correct
      sum=$((sum+actualsize))
      echo $sum

done<"$LISTFILES" 
echo $sum
```

Also your syntax is wrong:

you should do: `$((sum+actualsize))` check this for [bash aritmetics](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html)

Comment: Also the `for` loop should be converted to `while read file; do ... done<"$LISTFILES"`

Comment: @thom, sweet, I didn't know this one!

Answer (score 3):

You should use `while read` instead of `for ... $(...)`. The `while read` is faster and less error prone. Also, see the [stat](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stat) command for getting the file size. The stat command may vary from system to system, so see your manpage. This is using the one found on BSD/Mac OS X. Linux may be `stat -c%s`. That's what the Linux manpage says online. Again, use `man` to figure this out. Also, be waring of spaces in file names. Use quotes around `$file` to take this into account.

In answer to your question, you need to put math in `$((....))`:

```
while read file #for file in `cat $LISTFILES`
do
    echo "Processing files: '$file'"
    actualsize=$(stat -f%x "$file")
    sum=0
    sum=$(($sum+$actualsize))
    echo $sum
done < $LISTFILES  #Assuming this is a file that contains the list...
echo 'done'
echo $sum
```